# setTimeout breaking flow in JS?

Tags: javascript, comparison, equals

Could someone explain to me why this isn't working, the flow seems to be broken in my Javascript...

what always happens is this: the last if-statement of the "otherFunction" always evaluates to true, but it seems that since I got a timeout there, the return never happens.

Do I somehow need to pass the return back by first returning true from the anonymous timeOut-function to my "otherFunction" and then in turn from that to the callee? Not sure how to do that...

```
myObj.ready = function() {
    var self = this;

    var readyFlag = self.otherFunction();

    if (readyFlag == true) {
        $("#slide1").remove();
    }
    else {
        //If not fully transitioned in yet, postpone 1,5s
        setTimeout(function(){
            self.ready();
        },1500);

        return false; //end execution here, wait for timeout to pick it back up
    }
}

myObj.otherFunction = function() {
    //check twice (with a couple of milliseconds inbetwwen) and get the same value, transition must be finished...
    var check1 = $("#slide").css('-webkit-transform');

    setTimeout(function(){
        console.error('check1: '+check1); //print: none

        var check2 = $("#slide1").css('-webkit-transform');
        console.error('check2: '+check2); //print: none

        if (check1 == check2) {
            console.error('transition IS ready...');
            return true;
        }
        else {
            console.error('transition NOT ready...');
            console.error('check2: '+check2);
            return false;
        }

    },30);
}
```

Comment: You can't return data from the "timed-out" function to `otherFunction`. If I understood what you want correctly, you seem to be out of luck.

Comment: `myObj.otherFunction` doesn't return anything. The `return` statements return from the inner anonymous function, which isn't called until at least 30 ms after `otherFunction` finishes.

Comment: So I can't return a true here, I would have to restructure it so that instead of continuing the execution by a returned true, I would have to make a third function that gets called by the setTimeout upon true?

Comment: Both would be valid options.

Comment: Asynchronous and Synchronous, learn what that means. If you want to know when the second function is done, you need to use a callback or trigger an event.

Comment: Your setTimeout function would return undefined.

Comment: So, to do this You'll either group both Your functions into huge one or use callbacks

Comment: @AlexShilman: nope. [It returns a numerical ID of the timeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout), which can be used later with `window.clearTimeout()`

Comment: @Cerbrus check out my sample here: http://jsbin.com/AqoGijOD/1/edit

Comment: @AlexShilman: That's not the `setTimeout` function that's returning `undefined`, like you said. That's just the `sayYes` function returning `undefined`

Comment: @Cerbrus that's correct. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: @Cerbrus I meant to say the function that has the setTimeout in it (i.e. myObj.otherFunction) would return undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't return data from the "timed-out" function to `otherFunction`. If I understood what you want correctly, you seem to be out of luck.